# Problem with first page of data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

I'm working on creating a set of data driven pages of quarter sections in a township. QutrSecs is the layer, QTR is the Name field (e.g. NE, NW, etc.) and sort field is SECTIONS (e.g. 01 -36), so that pages will ordr by section 1, then section 2, and so on.

This works fine for all pages except the first page, where it displays the entire section. Name on that page is NE. I can't figure out why this would be the case, and more importantly, how to fix it. This should be something simple, but can't find it.

Comment: Can you check the extent of the first feature? (zoom to feature) It might be that the first feature's geometry is not what you think it is.

Comment: That was it! Whoever digitized the quarter section had a sliver extending all along the northern edge of the adjacent quarter section. Deleting the vertex fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Menno I recommend that you write up a quick answer of a few lines, which it sounds like recurvate would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the geometry of the first feature. It might be that the first feature's geometry is not what you think it is. It might have a multipart at an unsuspected location. This will cause the first page to zoom to an other extent that you wanted.